# ImageMagick Opencl version

Tags: imagemagick, opencl

I installed ImageMagick OpenCL as per the instructions in https://serverfault.com/questions/734854/why-is-imagemagick-with-opencl-slower-than-openmp
But when i check whether version of ImageMagick includes support for the OpenCL feature using
$ identify -version
It shows

> Version: ImageMagick 6.7.7-10 2014-03-06 Q16
>   http://www.imagemagick.org Copyright: Copyright (C) 1999-2012 ImageMagick Studio LLC 
>   Features: OpenMP

But it has to show the features as

> Features: DPC Cipher Modules OpenCL OpenMP

What else i am missing?? Is there any other steps i ve left out??